# How to override GlobalStyles in styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a monorepo maintained with yarn workspaces and the set up looks roughly like this:

```
- packages
  - app-1
  - app-2
  - app-3
  - theme
```

I export two things from `theme`:

```js
import ThemeProvider, { GlobalStyle } from "@scope/theme";
```

In "app-1" and "app-2", I'd like to keep the global styles as they are, but in "app-3", I'd like to override them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

you can setup the default global style and for each app assign it to injectGlobal;
because each time in each component you use injectGlobal you basically override it.

```js
/* global-styles.js */
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components'

injectGlobal`
  * { all: initial; }
`
```